# Как решить задачу и какой алгоритм нужно использовать?

Tags: python

Не понимаю как решить эту задачу. Какой алгоритм нужно использовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не понимаю как именно решать залачу. Почему в первом варианте вывод получился 18

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Comment: @David138 -  на вашей картинке слева подробнейшее объяснение алгоритма. Вы его хоть прочли, перед тем, как писать сюда вопрос? Сами попробовали применить к первому варианту? И что у вас получилось? Если у вас другой ответ., приведите его тут, мы попробуем помочь вам исправить ошибки.

Comment: @passant как раз по примере слева получилось, а справа варианты  -нет. видимо я не правильно пнимаю

Comment: Вот и напишите прямо в вопросе - как вы вычисляли и что у вас получилось

Comment: @CrazyElf А вы можете расписать как получился ответ 18 в первом варианте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм такой:

- создайте набор, в котором будут собраны все буквы из первого и второго слова по одному разу (используйте множество для этого)
- пройдите по этому набору букв и посчитайте модуль разницы количества каждой из этих букв в первом и во втором слове (используйте `.count`)
- сложите вместе полученные в предыдущем пункте значения

Comment: по первому пункту получается два множества из двух слов?

Comment: @David138 Можно по-разному сделать, но проще всего сделать два множества, из которых потом сделать одно с помощью пересечения множеств

Answer (score 0):

Вот так я решил

```
from collections import Counter
def f(a,b):
    a,b=Counter(a),Counter(b)
    diff = (a-b) | (b-a)
    return sum(diff.values())
#i1='wgrlpdxcfdhtte'
#i2='tvsajfjbygwzri'
i1=input()
i2=input()
result=f(i1,i2)
print(result)
```